# Drop down does not works on chrome, IE and works only on Firefox

Tags: google-maps, google-chrome, drop-down-menu

I use drop down list on my GMap to chose needed region. It works only on Firefox, in other browsers when i chose region it do nothing. Here's my code:

```
          $.getJSON("sample2.php", {}, function(data){
          $.each(data.places2, function(i, item){

                // $("#markers1").append('<li><a href="#" rel="' + i + '">' + item.title2 +              '</a></li>');
        $("#markers").append('<option value="' + i+ '">' + item.title2 +'</option>');
        latlngbounds2.extend(new google.maps.LatLng(item.lat2, item.lng2));
        map.setCenter( latlngbounds2.getCenter(), map.fitBounds(latlngbounds2));
        var marker2 = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(item.lat2, item.lng2),
            title: item.title2
            // map: map
        });
        arrMarkers2[i] = marker2;
        var infowindow2 = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
            content: "<h3>"+ item.title2 +"</h3>" +"<p>"
        });
        arrInfoWindows2[i] = infowindow2;
    });
});
 }
  $(function  (){

mapInit();

   // $('#markers option').click(function() {
     $("#markers option").live("click", function (){
    var i = $(this).attr("value");
    // Эта строка кода, закрывает все открытые балуны, для открытия выбранного
    for(x=0; x < arrInfoWindows2.length; x++){ arrInfoWindows2[x].close(); }
    //arrInfoWindows2[i].open(map, arrMarkers2[i]);
    map.setZoom(12);
    map.setCenter(arrMarkers2[i].getPosition());
    //  alert(arrMarkers2[i]);
    console.info(arrMarkers2[i]['title']);

});
});
```

This is HTML code:

```
       <div name="cont" id="container" >
     <select id="markers">
     <option>Select Region</option>
     </select>
      </div>
```

Can anybody help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try use `change` in dropdown instead `click` in option?

```
$("#markers").change(function() {
    var i = $(this).val();

    for (x=0; x < arrInfoWindows2.length; x++) {
        arrInfoWindows2[x].close();
    }

    map.setZoom(12);
    map.setCenter(arrMarkers2[i].getPosition());
    console.info(arrMarkers2[i]['title']);
});
```